# 引数に渡されるオブジェクトの型によって、引数の型を変更したい。シンプルな書き方は？

Tags: swift

下のように書いていますが、もっとシンプルな書き方はありせんか？    重複した部分が多く、冗長な気がするのですが。

```
func addSomeButton(view:AnyObject) {


    let viewForMyButton = UIView()

    //...


    //Viewにボタン追加
    if view is UITextView {
        (view as! UITextView).inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
    } else if view is UITextField {
        (view as! UITextField).inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そもそものメソッドを分割してしまうと言う手もありますね。

```
func addSomeButton(view: UITextView) {
    let viewForMyButton = UIView()

    // 共通の処理は別メソッドにくくり出す

    view.inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
}

func addSomeButton(view: UITextField) {
    let viewForMyButton = UIView()

    // 共通の処理を呼ぶ

    view.inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
}
```

---

他の方も書かれていますが『シンプルな書き方』は受け取る人によって変わるでしょうし、自分が好きなようにやれば良いと思いますよ。

Answer (score 2):

`inputAccessoryView` は `UITextView` と `UITextField` の共通の祖先 `UIResponder` のプロパティですから、

```
if view is UIResponder {
    (view as! UIResponder).inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
}
```

という感じでよろしいのではないでしょうか。

パラメータ `view` の型を `UIResponder` か `UIView` に変更できれば、型判定も `as` も必要ありません。

(追記)
コメントで指摘があったように、この回答は間違いです。動きません。

Comment: 実際にXcode上でコードを書いてみればすぐ分かるはずなのですが、`UIResponder`クラス(や、それを継承しただけの`UIView`)の`inputAccessoryView`はread-onlyプロパティなので代入することができません。従って`UIResponder`や`UIView`にキャストしても`inputAccessoryView`への代入はコンパイル時にエラーになります。

Comment: おお、本当ですね。この回答は間違いでした。

Answer (score 1):

例えばswitch-caseを使うとこんな書き方ができます。

```
    switch view {
    case let v as UITextView:
        v.inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
    case let v as UITextField:
        v.inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
    default:
        break
    }
```

行数はかえって増えてしまってますね。

if文にもcaseパターンが使えるので、こんな書き方もできます。

```
    if case let v as UITextView = view  {
        v.inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
    } else if case let v as UITextField = view {
        v.inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
    }
```

この場面でif文中にcaseパターンを使うのは少し無理矢理って感じもしますが。

`as?`演算子を使えば、caseパターンではなくif-letでも同じことが書けます。

```
    if let v = view as? UITextView {
        v.inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
    } else if let v = view as? UITextField {
        v.inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
    }
```

これが文字数的には一番短いし、一般的でしょうか。

こんな前準備をしておけば、

```
protocol InputAccessoryViewType: class {
    var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {get set}
}
extension UITextView: InputAccessoryViewType {}
extension UITextField: InputAccessoryViewType {}
```

こんな書き方もできるんですが。

```
    if let v = view as? InputAccessoryViewType {
        v.inputAccessoryView = viewForMyButton
    }
```

準備まで入れるととても「シンプル」とは言えないですね。

「もっとシンプルな書き方はありせんか？」と言う質問は少々「曖昧すぎる」気がするので、『「`as!`による強制キャスト」のように「使わなくて済むなら使いたくない機能」を出来るだけ省く』と解釈させてもらいました。思いつくのはこんなものでしょうか。